# Dynamic vs Static SQL with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

The "Where" clause of my SQL will vary depending on the values provided. I wrote 2 versions (Dynamic and static). I read that Dynamic is the way to go if we have multiple parameters with a variable where clause. Also, this is just a sample, my real SQL has many more conditions, but something along these lines. Which among the two is the right choice for this scenario?

Dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)='SELECT ID,Name,sex,street,city,state,zip,phone FROM Test';
DECLARE @whereSql VARCHAR(2000) = 'WHERE city= @City';
DECLARE @OrderBy VARCHAR(2000) = 'order by name';   
IF(@Name IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
SET @Name =  @Name + '%'
SET @whereSql = @whereSql + ' ' + 'AND name like @Name';
end
IF(@Gender IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
SET @whereSql = @whereSql + ' ' + 'AND sex =' + '@Gender';
END
IF(@Address IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
SET @Address = '%' + @Address + '%'
SET @whereSql = @whereSql + ' ' + 'AND street like ' + '@Address';
END
SET @SQL = @SQL +' ' + @whereSql + ' '+ @OrderBy;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Gender VARCHAR(10), @Name VARCHAR(200), @Address VARCHAR(250)', @Gender,@Name,@Address;
```

Static SQL:

```
SELECT ID,Name,sex,street,city,state,zip,phone FROM Test T1 WHERE
(@Name IS NULL OR (T1.Name LIKE +'%'+ @Name + '%')) 
AND
(@Gender is null OR (T1.sex = @Gender))
AND
(@Address is null or (T1.street LIKE +'%'+ @Address + '%'))
```

Comment: Is there a question there?  You should probably read Erland Sommarskog's classic treatement of this subject: http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Comment: I'm trying to figure the approach I need to finalize.

Comment: You got it the other way around, first one is dynamic and second one is static. And the static is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks @Anand! Is it because there is a flaw in my Dynamic sql or am I overdoing the task?

Comment: I don't say that because you have a flaw in your dynamic SQL. I say that as a general rule to avoid dynamic SQL because it opens up the possibility of injection attacks. I say that because you should be reusing your execution plans and I say that because your static SQL is much more elegant way of executing your particular query.

Comment: @Anand: Thank you so much! :)